# How to attach multiple displays to Android?

Tags: external-display

I would like to have an Android setup with one primary and two secondary hardware displays. I am wondering, if it is possible at all? I know you can have primary and secondary screens according to the documentation, and Android have Display Manager supporting multiple displays. But would a total of three displays work?

I am running Android 11.

Comment: I don't think you are talking about regular Android installed on some smartphone. You are talking about Android-x86 or some other Android-OS for PCs. Because usually you don't "setup" Android somewhere. A device comes with Android or not. The only other option is to change the AOSP source code and develop you own Android based custom ROM (a topic that is considered off-topic here).

Comment: Yes and no, you can plug Android device into HDMI extender and have at least 1 external display. Technically you can use multiple HDMIs to connect to multiple displays. I tried successfully with only with one HDMI.
But yes I'm talking mostly about AOSP ans it more configurable.
But it should be irrelevant as Android since version 10 has innate multiple display support.

Comment: So you are talking about displays connected via USB-C port to an Android phone? If that works and how (MHL, DisplayPort alternate stream, ..) is very device specific.

Comment: By "Android [...] 10 has innate multiple display support", is this you're referring to: [Using more than two displays](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/display/multi_display/displays#more_displays)?

Comment: @AndrewT. Yes, exactly this what I'm talking about.